# No plus or minus button in Xcode localization settings

Tags: ios, xcode, button, localization

I need to translate an iOS-Application within two days, but my XCode versions (4.4 and 4.5 Developer Preview) both don't give me the option to add another language. I only get the option to click "Make localized.." but I can only choose english and after choosing it, there are no plus and minus buttons in the utility inspector in Xcode - with no file or project i tried.

Am I missing something here?

**Edit:**
This is how it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 101, accepted):

It moved to the starting in Xcode 4.4 .

[image]

Comment: Tanks! How true it is: a picture is worth a thousand words! :)

Comment: Kudos for you, it took me almost an hour to find this.

Comment: Kudos here too, and... Seriously, Apple, get it together!

Comment: Yes, this made my day!!

Answer (score 4):

I just meet with this problem and I was using xcode 4.5 preview 3. Couldn't believe apple have made this kind of mistakes and not fixed it even when its at preview 3. Therefore I believe they just have changed the way localisation work so I poke around the UI until I finally found it.

They have shifted it. You first have to add the language you want to the project first. Then after it will appear as a check box item in the UI you show. To add the language you need to click go to **Project** -> **Info** then click *"+"* to add new localizations.

Hopes that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help me. I don't think that this is a "new" place for the localization feature but an alternative one. I really think that this is a beta issue, but you can find a work-around solution in the Developer Forums if your interested in. Just search there for "localization" in iOS 6 part. :)

Comment: @Dschee I think it actually is a shift. This is also the case in the latest *release* non-beta Xcode (4.4) having moved locations since the previous release. I'm not sure why you're saying Nyon's response didn't help you. This is apparently the way it is done now and you should mark his answer as the correct answer. That's not to say they won't eventually add it back to where you're expecting it, but it is clear that right now, doing what Nyon said is the right way.

Comment: Oh sorry, you were right, I simply didn't find the right place to look up so it didm't work for me. I clicked on my Project name and thought, that's the step "Project" in the description (but I was in my App target), then I clicked "info" and clicked plus button – the following picture shows the result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5n7jit3ore1tk35/screenshot.png

This of course was my fault, I realized my fault after seeing the picture of someone else posted below – because I think others could have the same problem, I'll +1 this answer and correct answer the one with the picture. :)

Comment: yes, agreed! AAPL is so inconsistent, they move things around in nearly every minor version of xcode, and change the way things are done in every version of iOS! They should learn from MSFT.. even though they absorb a lot of their talents, they never incorporate any of the great stuff MSFT had, they should just outsource the tools dev to the Visual Studio team instead!

Flame wars aside, I agreed with Nyon's answer, it helped me, but it will be clearer with pic though or preferable with gif animation like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13201690/474330

Answer (score 1):

The buttons scroll out of view when the "+" is used to extend the list.  Use the mouse to grab the bar right below the list of localizations and drag it down to make more room, and the buttons will be visible again.  Then you can click on the "+" to see a menu of additional localizations.

Comment: Either I don't understand what you mean or that's not the problem. I've added a picture of how it looks right now.

Comment: Thanks for the picture.  No, I definitely see "+" and "-" buttons; this is probably a bug in the Developer Preview versions, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Xcode 4.5 DP3 completely miss the +/- buttons in the localization pane.
I tried Nyon solution to add an additional language (actually before seeing this post).
Doing so, I can add a language into the project but I cannot use that new language to localize my files.
But thanks to him, I know now that it is the issue with Xcode DP3.

So, what did was very simple: **I use the old Xcode 4.3 to localize my file** (with + button in the localization pane).
Then, I have two versions of the files (one for each language, nicely organized into appropriate lproj). 
Then I switch back to Xcode 4.5 DP3.
Now, both languages (en and the new one) appear in the localization pane.
And this time, for all my files!

That is, you have to add a language only once in Xcode 4.3, afterwards, the new language will appear in your language list as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can add languages in Xcode 4.5 like above.

Comment: i would like to add that you should make sure to select the project, and not the target!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is not complete!... If you start a project for a non English, Japanese, French or German language (in xCode 4.6), then you will be a bit lost on how to localize your resources.

If you just go and try to add a new language as stated by kamesh above, you'll find you can't if you didn't FIRST localized at least one of your resources in the default provided languages by xcode.

So, localize at least one of your resources needed to be localized, and then, add the language you need to add as kamesh, then the next modal presented by xcode will let you add any resources to that new language. (not very intuitive and definitely not documented by apple.)