# Change UIView layout programmatically for iPhone 5

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, resize

I am trying to change the layout of my UIView programmatically, and not by using Auto Layout, as I am trying to deploy this app for iOS 4 and up. I basically set my view up with the screen height at 455(iPhone 5)(I know the actual screen size is 568 points, but I have a tab bar on the bottom so I am assuming the size shown in IB has taken that into account). I recorded the origin of all of my buttons and labels relative to the longer screen size and programmatically changed them to how I preferred them. The problem is, some of the buttons and labels are going off the screen now, so I think I have to perform some kind of conversion to keep them in bounds, but I am not sure what. See the pictures attached below:

Image before my initMethod is called to change button and label origins
[image]
Image after my initMethod is called to change the origin
[image]
View properties in XCode for the old screen size
[image]
This is how I want the view to Look. I moved the buttons around and recorded the origin of each.
[image]
Picture of my init method in viewWillAppear. Notice how the frame of the label is zero.
[image]
Here is the code I used:

```
-(void)initView
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    if (screenBounds.size.height == 480) {
        //iphone 4,4s
        //done
    }else if(screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
        //iphone 5
        CGRect frame;
        //Static Professor label
        frame = [staticProfessorLabel frame];
        frame.origin.x = 48;
        frame.origin.y = 218;
        [staticProfessorLabel setFrame:frame];
        //Professor Label
        frame = [professorLabel frame];
        frame.origin.x = 192;
        frame.origin.y = 218;
        [professorLabel setFrame:frame];
        //show button
        frame = [showProfessorButton frame];
        frame.origin.x = 67;
        frame.origin.y = 258;
        [showProfessorButton setFrame:frame];
        //clear proff button
        frame = [clearProfessor frame];
        frame.origin.x = 240;
        frame.origin.y = 258;
        //note label
        frame = [bottomNote frame];
        frame.origin.x = 160;
        frame.origin.y = 310;
        [bottomNote setFrame:frame];
        //search button
        frame = [searchButton frame];
        frame.origin.x = 158;
        frame.origin.y = 424;
        [searchButton setFrame:frame];
        //spinner
        frame = [actIndicator frame];
        frame.origin.x = 266;
        frame.origin.y = 424;
        [actIndicator setFrame:frame];
    }
}
```

Also, I am calling this in the viewDidAppear method because when I call it in viewDidLoad, none of the buttons and labels give me a valid frame(I am guessing they are not initialized yet).

Comment: You said you want to “change the layout of my UIView programmatically, and not by using Auto Layout”, but the screen shots show that your storyboards have autolayout turned on.  You need to turn it off if you want to set the frames manually.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13201690/77567) if you don't know how to disable autolayout in your storyboard.

Comment: If you comment below, I will make your answer as the accepted one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Xcode screenshots show that your storyboard contains constraints, so we can tell that your storyboard has autolayout turned on.  If you want to set the view frames directly in code, you have to turn off autolayout.

Take a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13201690/77567) if you need help turning off autolayout on your storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Your hard-coded coordinates are simply wrong. Just double-check your values.

For example, `bottomNote` starts at `x` 160, which is clearly too far to the right.

Comment: I commented out all of the x values since the only things that need to be changed are the y values anyways. Where should I call this method so it is only called once. Everytime I change views and come back to this one, the user can see the view changing. I can't call it in viewDidLoad because the frame properties of the subviews are not set up yet

Comment: try `viewWillAppear`. All the view should already be layed out, but not visible yet.

Comment: Nope, the frame is still 0 for all of these if I call initView there.

Comment: Impossible. Something is wrong with your setup reading from IB/Storyboard.

Comment: I added a picture in my post. It shows the frame returned being zero after being called in the ViewWillAppear method

Comment: This is the printed description as well:
Printing description of self->staticProfessorLabel:
<UILabel: 0x1dd9ae00; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = 'Professor:'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1dd9ae90>>