# IB Elements Jump Back To Original Position

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIView Animation Inconsistent Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388835/uiview-animation-inconsistent-result)

I have an iPhone app where I've set a lot of the UI elements of one of the view controllers up in Interface Builder so that when the view loads, those elements animate out to to where I want them. However, on one of the buttons, I have a tap gesture which dims the screens by bringing a black UIView to the front with its alpha property set to .5.

Whenever the background dimmer comes to the front, all the UI Elements that I've animated to different places jump back to where they originally were placed.

I wish I could post code but I can't since it's a business venture.

Anyone think they have an idea?

Edit: An obvious fix is once I bring up the background dimmer, just reanimate everything else back to where it should be. But that's a messy solution and I would rather just have them stay where they were animated to.

Also, I animated them by setting the frame using CGRectMake and such if that helps.

EDIT 2:

The jump is being caused by calling:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:view];
```

I don't know how to stop that from happening though.

Comment: Are you sure that the cause of the problem is the background dimmer coming to the front, or could they just be happening at the same time? Can you comment out the code that brings the background dimmer to the front, and see if the problem persists?

Comment: Ok so it happens without the dimmer. Good call. It's happening on calls to bringSubviewToFront.

Comment: It could have something to do with constraints ( see Rob's link), but I can't duplicate it. I have a little test app that I made that animates labels (by setting the frame). Those labels have constraints set up in IB, but that doesn't keep the animation from working. I added another view, like your dimmer view, and nothing happens when I call bringSubviewToFront: (other than what's supposed to).

Answer (score 0):

Have to give credit to @rob mayoff. It has to do with using autolayouts in storyboards as talked about in this question: [Autolayouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201586/nsinvalidunarchiveoperationexception-could-not-instantiate-class-named-nslayout/13201690#13201690)