# (Swift) I want to move a view, but the code doesn't work, How to fix it?

Tags: swift

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqvEK.png)   the red piece is my button view with 5 buttons on it.

buttonView.frame.origin.y = 800

I wanted to use this code to move the view out of screen, than make a animation, but it doesn't move.

did I write a wrong code?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXCOQ.gif)
I tried to use button to control it, it just got back.

Please help me, thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIView Animation Inconsistent Result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388835/uiview-animation-inconsistent-result)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. I don't know what doesn't work with you. But you want animate your view, try this

```
testView.frame.origin.y -= 50

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { () -> Void in

    self.testView.frame.origin.y += 50
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I knew how to animate my view, but I just don't know how to set the position of the view, I tried buttonView.frame.origin.y -= 50 , this doesn't work. please help me.

Comment: try `buttonView.center.y = 400`
Please make sure your view connection is correct.

Comment: No, it works for me. Try to add another view and move it. if it works, remove your old view and use new view.

Comment: I tried to create a new project, the code work perfectly, I think I must made some stupid setting on old project,

Comment: I found the problem, it may be a bug, I record a video to show that.   https://youtu.be/AF5_cxQYkl8

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, just set in viewDidLoad:

```
self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```