# GoogleAnalytics 2.0b3 ios 5 support

Tags: ios5, ios6

Have any information about support google analitics 2.0 for iOS 5 ?
I got this error on iOS 5

```
GoogleAnalytics 2.0b3 void GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *) (GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler.m:41): Uncaught exception: Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint handler threw exception
```

Can I upload my app to appstore with this google analitics  2.0 beta library? Because i know that we cant upload app with "beta" information ..

Comment: I just got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

This is problem with libraries, try change social.framework, adsupport.framework  and accounts.framework to optional in build phases.

Comment: I have now: GoogleAnalytics 2.0b4 void GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *) (GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler.m:41): Uncaught exception: CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0xe0dd380 <x-coredata://09EC0CC5-BC0F-4A7C-95F4-6768D5EB7A3E/FileTable/p3326>'
libc++abi.dylib: handler threw exception   - any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I did had the same error and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201586/nsinvalidunarchiveoperationexception-could-not-instantiate-class-named-nslayout) i had to uncheck autolayout for my xib. Worked for me.