# 'Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint' while auto layout is disabled

Tags: xcode, ios5, ios-simulator

My application is crashing on iOS 5 when I call presentModalViewController on a new view with the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint'

I know that this error should be fixed by unchecking auto layout, but it isn't. I unchecked it in all my nibs.

The very puzzling part is that using a view I created one month ago, there is no crash, but using one that I created today, it crashes.

Is there another setting that I should know about?

I'm using XCode 4.5.2, with SDK 6.0, and deployment target 5.0.

Comment: it looks like creating a new (crashing) nib then copying the content of the previous one inside makes it work. I don't know why yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you would have solved the problem by now. 
But for others who would stumble into this post, please check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13201690/942966

Comment: The autolayout didn't fix the problem for me, but that was because I copied some old code from a project written with an old XCode. But your answer is the right one for the common occurences of this bug.