# How to move UIButton programmatically. Objective-C Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I've seen some solutions, none of which have worked for my issue.

I have a `UIButton` created by simply drag/dropping into the `UIViewController` in Storyboard editor.

The `UIButton` has an outlet linked to the .h file for the `UIViewController` associated to that view. It is also Synthesized in the `.m` file.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *answerButton;
```

I want to change the location of the button during run time like this;

```
CGRect btFrame = answerButton.frame;
btFrame.origin.x = xOne;
btFrame.origin.y = yOne;
answerButton.frame = btFrame;
```

However whenever I try this, the button refuses to move.

All other editing functions (like `setTitle` etc) are functional, but for some reason the frame won't move how I want it to.

Comment: Use the gesture functionality

Comment: Are you using auto-layout?

Comment: @Vikas, the user isn't moving the button. The placement of the button is determined by some selections made previously by them. xOne, yOne are 2 int values creating a point which is changed based on selections made previously. I just want to be able to set frame to these known int values.

Comment: @SamBo Make sure you don't have autolayout enabled in your storyboard.  [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13201690/77567) if you need help figuring out whether it's enabled and turning it off.

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much Rob & Zaphod!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply uncheck "Use Autolayout" in the file inspector..

Answer (score 7):

.h file

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UIButton *theButton;
}
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *theButton;
-(IBAction)moveTheButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m file

```
-(IBAction)moveTheButton:(id)sender{
CGRect btFrame = theButton.frame;
btFrame.origin.x = 90;
btFrame.origin.y = 150;
theButton.frame = btFrame;
```

}

This code moves the button from one point to another.

Answer (score 4):

Replace your code by the below, which includes code to remove auto resizing mask.

```
CGRect btFrame = answerButton.frame;
btFrame.origin.x = xOne;
btFrame.origin.y = yOne;
answerButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
answerButton.frame = btFrame;
```

Comment: Did you NSLog xOne, yOne and check what it is?