# Do multiple timers with same interval interfere with each other in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I have two `NSTimers` in Objective-C. One of them causes an object to slowly move up the iPhone screen, while the other one is a score timer that adds one point to the score every 0.5 seconds. The timer that moves the object up the screen also has an interval of 0.5 seconds. These timers are called/activated when a button is pressed. When the button is pressed, the object does slowly move up the screen for that 0.5 seconds. After the 0.5 seconds, one point is added to the score, which works correctly.

The problem, however, is that right after the 0.5 seconds the object moves back to its original location at the bottom of the screen. It then starts moving up again for the 0.5 seconds, and promptly moves right back to the bottom of the screen. The scoring timer works perfectly, adding 1 point every 0.5 seconds.

### Code

```
-(IBAction)play:(id)sender{

    gametimer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05f target:self selector:@selector(gameLoop) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    scoretimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05f target:self selector:@selector(scorechange) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)scorechange{

    score = score + 1;
    scorelab.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", score];

}

-(void)gameLoop{

    balstarted = YES;
    bal.center = CGPointMake(bal.center.x, bal.center.y - balspeed);

}
```

Once again, instead of moving up the screen as it should, my object, bal, moves up only a few pixels (for that 0.5 seconds) and then resets itself to its previous position.

Comment: You could test whether or not they're interfering by disabling the timer that increases the score. Based on how it's resetting to the initial position, it seems likely to be unrelated to having a second timer (nothing immediately pops out in the shown code, though).

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the animation, not a problem with using two timers.  If you animate a view's frame but do not set the new frame value into the view, the view's frame will "reset".

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Nate Chandler, how would I set the new frame value into the view?

Comment: Kitsune, if I stop the scoring timer then the bal object moves up the screen perfectly, and the timer works. However, when I add the scoring timer, the bal object doesn't move up the screen correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### REVISED

You have autolayout enabled.  When you change `scorelab.text`, the `UILabel` notifies the autolayout system that its intrinsic content size has changed, which causes autolayout to reset the positions and sizes of every view.  Since you haven't changed the constraints on `bal`, autolayout resets its position.

You can either [turn off autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13201690/77567), or you can modify `bal`'s constraints instead of setting its `center` directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think I'm adding an animation necessarily. I'm not completely familiar with CABasicAnimation or CALayer. Instead, I'm moving the object by adding an NSTimer and in the timer's selector method, I change the object's center by a few pixels. The timer causes this object to move up the screen by small increments.

Comment: @robmayoff, drats! You beat me to it -- I was just about to post this same thing. If you use autolayout, and your object has a constraint to the bottom of the view, you can make an IBOutlet to that constraint (con1 in my example) and use: self.con1.constant += balSpeed; to move the object, instead of setting the center.

Answer (score 1):

The selectors are both executed in the same thread where you schedule the timer.
As long as you schedule both timers from the same thread, there isn't any interference.If in the scheduled methods you use shared object, there isn't a race condition.
There is a race condition only if you schedule the timers from different threads, and they use shared objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Are these timers scheduled in different threads? Sorry I'm not familiar with threads.

Comment: no, it will be in same thread. If you want to run it in different thread then you need to spawn a thread.