# resignFirstResponder changes frame value

Tags: ios, objective-c, resignfirstresponder

I have a `LoginViewController` with two text fields and a button. I used storyboard, so these are not created programmatically. They are below each other.

Here's the .h file

```c
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *pw1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *pw2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *loginBtn;
- (IBAction)loginBtnPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)singleTapRecognized:(id)sender;
@end
```

The `pw2` is shown only on the first run, when the user creates a new password and confirms it in `pw2`. Otherwise it is hidden. In that case I move the button up to put the button closer to `pw1`.

```c
    CGSize size = self.pw2.frame.size;
    CGRect rect = self.loginBtn.frame;
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y-size.height, rect.size.width,rect.size.height);
    [self.loginBtn setFrame:newFrame];
```

So far, so good. Up to here all works as expected. But now.....

- when I leave the `pw1` blank, the program checks the field, detects it is empty, hides the keyboard and shows a `UIAlertView`. This works fine.
- when I put in some characters that are not correct, the program does almost the same, but moves the button down to its original position.
- same behavior when some characters entered and tapped anywhere in the view

I found out, that this only happens, when I am hiding the keyboard. Otherwise the button stays at its "upped" position as expected.

Here is my keyboard hide:

```c
-(void) hideKeyboard {
    if (self.pw1.isFirstResponder)
        [self.pw1 resignFirstResponder];
    else if (self.pw2.isFirstResponder)
        [self.pw2 resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Any ideas what happens?

Sorry about my english. English is not my native language.

Comment: To hide keyboard you can use `[self.view endEditing:YES]`.

Comment: Problem is that button change position to original when you hide keyboard? Please tell more details (e.g. show storyboards or more code)

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIView layout being reset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087245/uiview-layout-being-reset)

Comment: Thank you. It was the auto layout. When switching off, all works as expected. What i don't understand is the difference in the behavior, when i am entering characters or leave them blank. Thx to rob.

Answer (score 1):

I want to share my solution with you. I am sure there is a more elegant way to code, but this one works fine more me.

I added property in the .h file to hold the new constraint for the button.

```c
@property NSLayoutConstraint *loginButtonVerticalSpace;
```

Then i add a routine to find the "old" constraint as defined in the storyboard.

```
-(NSLayoutConstraint *) findButtonConstraintForItem:(id) item
                                         secondItem:(id) secondItem     //may be nil
                                     firstAttribute:(NSLayoutAttribute)firstAttribute
                                    secondAttribute:(NSLayoutAttribute)secondAttribute
    {
        NSArray *cons = self.view.constraints;

        for (NSLayoutConstraint *ns in cons) {
        if (ns.firstItem==item)
        {
           if (ns.firstAttribute==firstAttribute)
           {
               if (secondItem==nil)
                   return ns;
               if (ns.secondItem==secondItem && ns.secondAttribute==secondAttribute)
                   return ns;
           }
        }

    }
    return nil;
}
```

And at least i changed my "moveButton" method to the following:

```
- (void) moveButtonUp{
    NSLayoutConstraint *consOld = [self findButtonConstraintForItem:self.loginBtn
                                                         secondItem:self.pw1
                                                     firstAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                    secondAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom];
    if (!consOld)   // should not happen
        return;

    if (self.loginButtonVerticalSpace)   // work already done
        return;

    CGSize size = self.pw2.frame.size;

    self.loginButtonVerticalSpace =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                   constraintWithItem:self.loginBtn
                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                               toItem:self.pw1
                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                            multiplier:1.0
                                              constant:consOld.constant-size.height];

    self.loginButtonVerticalSpace.priority=1000;
    [self.view addConstraint:self.loginButtonVerticalSpace];
    [self.view removeConstraint:consOld];
}
```

Thank you so much, guys....