# scrollView Swift displacing buttons within the scrollview, comes back to there original places, when scrolling is done

Tags: ios, swift, view, uiscrollview, scrollview

I need to implement scrollView with two views in it.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
       scrollView.contentSize.height = 500

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view2: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!


    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        view1.frame.origin.x = 200
    }
}
```

when i tap the button, i shift one of the views, over the other view using(whose origin x is at 200). This is happening successfully.

The problem is, as I start scrolling, the first view goes back to its old position.

Can anybody provide a solution to this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Video: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B06Tv5JREcB8ZDNxZG9RZ24zZ28

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087245/uiview-layout-being-reset and many others. You cannot modify the frame of a view directly if you are using autolayout constraints.

Comment: I wish to use this app for all sizes of phones. Is there some other way to fix this?