# No options for autoresizing window in size inspector (XCode 4.5.2)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

in XCode 4.5.2, when I created a new XIB file, I don't get an options to use the auto-resizing window in the size inspector (on the right hand side). But if I use old Xib files, that was created in another project, I can see the auto-resizing options.

What I am seeing now:

[image: no-options-for-auto-resizing]

But I want to see/ have an options like the following image:
[image: have-options-for-auto-resizing]

I am using XCode 4.5.2

How can I have auto resizing options ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException: Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201586/nsinvalidunarchiveoperationexception-could-not-instantiate-class-named-nslayout)

Comment: See the answer in that link to turn off Autolayout.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In Xcode, go to File Inspector window just uncheck checkbox given for "Use Autolayout" and switch to Size inspector you will see autoresizing window there.