# iOS: Combining storyboard and programatic UI setup

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I tend to combine using the storyboard and code to set up my UI's. I haven't touched objective-c in a little while, but I do remember to get UI code working properly, I would have to add the 'performSelectorOnMainThread' code like this under ViewDidLoad. (if you don't do this, and placed the code under uiSetup under viewDidLoad, or even called [self uiSetup] without performSelectorOnMainThread, the code would not run, due to lazy-loading i believe)

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(uiSetup) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

and then in 'uiSetup' some things like this...

```
- (void)uiSetup
{
    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor blueColor], nil];
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

        UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        subview.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * colors.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
}
```

I'm trying to do this project properly, so I'm wondering, is there a more efficent way to do this? Maybe another method I should override?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is exactly how you combine storyboard with programatic setup.  Just make sure you choose the proper function from the family: `viewDidLoad:` `viewWillApear:` `viewDidAppear:`.  Also, you should not need to use `performSelectorOnMainThread: withObject: waitUntilDone:` to call your `uiSetup` function.  If you are having a problem with that, then you might consider posting another question about that.

Comment: that is exactly my question, if I do not use 'performSelectorOnMainThread' the code will fail to execute, a byproduct of apple's lazy loading ui

Comment: I use `[self functionName]` in my `viewDidLoad:` and it works just fine.  Why don't you post your `viewDidLoad:` implementation?

Comment: as i am doing a simple scroll-view test, all that is in my viewDidLoad is the [super viewDidLoad]. When I have [self uiSetup], the scroll view does not get populated with the colors, but with the [performSelectorOnMainThread] it does.

Comment: moving the [self uiSetup] line under viewDidAppear fixes this, but if [uiSetup] had complex setup code, it would not be user-friendly as things slowly appeared to the user

Comment: It sounds like your instance is being overwritten by the nib loading, however I tried to recreate what you described and the colors are loading just fine.  Anyway, `performSelectorOnMainThread:` would be an acceptable condition, or you can move it to `viewWillAppear:` and use `[self uiSetup]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to override `viewDidLoad` like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self uiSetup];
}
```

Make sure to call `[super viewDidLoad];`, that the class you have is selected as the class for the View Controller in the Storyboard, and that you have connected `scrollView` to a scroll view in the Storyboard.

`viewDidLoad` is always called on the UI (Main) thread, so there should be no reason to use `performSelectorOnMainThread`

Comment: I have done all that you have suggested. As I replied to WolfLink: i am doing a simple scroll-view test, all that is in my viewDidLoad is the [super viewDidLoad]. When I have [self uiSetup], the scroll view does not get populated with the colors, but with the [performSelectorOnMainThread] it does.

Comment: Can you add `NSLog(@"Scroll View: %@, Frame: %@", [self.scrollView debugDescription], NSStringFromCGRect(self.scrollView.frame))` to the first line of `uiSetup` and tell us what the output is with and without `performSelectorOnMainThread`?

Comment: Sure thing! With `performSelectorOnMainThread` -> `2013-03-16 19:09:19.626 scrolltest[9178:c07] Scroll View: <UIScrollView: 0x75c9b90; frame = (20 20; 280 378); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = TM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x75ca470>; layer = <CALayer: 0x75c9d60>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>, Frame: {{20, 20}, {280, 378}}`

Comment: without `performSelectorOnMainThread` -> `2013-03-16 19:10:43.733 scrolltest[9214:c07] Scroll View: <UIScrollView: 0x71978e0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = TM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7198200>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7197ab0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>, Frame: {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have Autolayout enabled on your storyboard, and yet your uiSetup method depends on non-zero frame values. Under Autolayout, frames aren't calculated at viewDidLoad, but later on in the life cycle. Adding the performSelectorOnMainThread call queues the call to uiSetup on the main thread so it is performed *after* layout is complete, however as you've noticed this isn't the nicest looking code.

Either:

- Change your uiSetup method to use Autolayout constraints or fixed frame sizes (this would be my preferred option, I'm an [autolayout lover](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/31/visual-format-language-for-autolayout/).
- Call it from `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (you'd need to take care as this method is called more often) or `viewDidAppear`
- Turn off Autolayout on your storyboard (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201586/nsinvalidunarchiveoperationexception-could-not-instantiate-class-named-nslayout).