# xcode UILabel resizing and repositioning not working

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimage, uilabel

I have been trying to get this working for much longer than I care to admin, but I have searched just about every s.o article there is and none of the solutions seem to be doing anything...

My problem is that I am trying to resize a title (UILabel) based on the amount of text, after resizing the title I want to move the image 100 pixels below the title.

The image frame shows that the value has changed to what it has been calculated to be but there is never a change in the application, it only shows the design that was made in the storyboard.

Storyboard layout:

- View

  - Scroll View

    - Image View
    - Label - TItle

The code below shows some printouts of values, without running it an example of those are:

```
Before: [0.000000]
After: [24.000000]
Label Expected Size: 280.000000, 96.000000
After Title Assign: [96.000000]
Image Y Before: [0.000000]
Image Y After: [196.000000]
```

Code:

```
self.Title.text = NewsCell.Title;
self.Image.image = NewsCell.Image;

// fit title
printf("Before: [%f]\n", self.Title.frame.size.height);
[self.Title sizeToFit];
printf("After: [%f]\n", self.Title.frame.size.height);

//self.Title.frame = CGRectMake(20, 5, 280, self.Title.frame.size.height);
self.Title.numberOfLines = 0;

CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(280, 100);
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [self.Title.text sizeWithFont:self.Title.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:self.Title.lineBreakMode];

self.Title.frame = CGRectMake(20,0,expectedLabelSize.width, expectedLabelSize.height);
printf("Label Expected Size: %f, %f\n", expectedLabelSize.width, expectedLabelSize.height);
printf("After Title Assign: [%f]\n", self.Title.frame.size.height);   


// set image location to be bototm of title + 100
printf("Image Y Before: [%f]\n", self.Image.frame.origin.y);
double titleBottom = self.Title.frame.origin.y + self.Title.frame.size.height + 100;
self.Image.frame = CGRectMake(0, titleBottom, 320, 200);
printf("Image Y After: [%f]\n", self.Image.frame.origin.y);


// set description location
double imageBottom = self.Image.frame.size.height + self.Image.frame.origin.y + 5;

// description expand
[self.Description.text stringByAppendingString: @"\n\n © 2013 Geekosystem, LLC"];
[self.Description sizeToFit];
self.Description.frame = CGRectMake(20, imageBottom, 280, self.Description.frame.size.height);
self.Description.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Comment: Is autolayout turned on in your storyboard?  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13201690/77567) will show you how to find out, if you're not sure.

Comment: In what method is this code running?