# setFrame won't do anything

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a problem with an app that won't set frames outside -init and -viewWillLayoutSubviews methods. What should happen when one taps the editButton is an animation that will hide the editor view. Nonetheless, nothing happens as I test it. The problem doesn't come from the animation method since the -setFrame method as it - not included in the block - doesn't work neither.

Here is the code :

```
-(id)init {

    if (self = [super init]) {

        editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(editButtonTapped)];
        doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonTapped)];


        editor = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [editor setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
        editor.clipsToBounds = YES;
        editorIsOpen = YES;        

        portraitRegularModeEditorRect = CGRectMake(15, 59, 738, 100);
        portraitClosedEditorEditorRect = CGRectMake(15, 59, 738, 0);


    }
    return self;

}


- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[self view] addSubview:editor];
    [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

}


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self setForRegularMode];

}




-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {

    UIInterfaceOrientation io = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (io == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || io == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

        //portrait
        [editor setFrame:portraitRegularModeEditorRect];


     } else {

        //landscape

     }


}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


-(void)editButtonTapped {

    [self setForScenarioLinesEditingMode];

}

-(void)doneButtonTapped {

    [self setForRegularMode];

}


-(void)setForRegularMode {

    editingMode = CPRegularMode;    

    if (!editorIsOpen) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut animations:^(void){

            [editor setFrame:portraitRegularModeEditorRect];

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            editorIsOpen = YES;

        }];

    }


    [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:editButton,nil]];

}



-(void)setForScenarioLinesEditingMode {

    editingMode = CPScenarioLinesEditingMode;

    if (editorIsOpen) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut animations:^(void){

            [editor setFrame:portraitClosedEditorEditorRect];

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            editorIsOpen = NO;

        }];

    }

    [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:doneButton,nil]];


}
```

If anyone can help, thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Are your `setFrame:` methods actually called?

Comment: I wish I knew. What I can say is everything before and everything after is called. How can I check?

Comment: Debugger, for example. Or just `NSLog` the `frame` and the `editor.

Comment: Alright, apparently the `setFrame:` method is called because when I `NSLog(@"%f",editor.frame.size.height);` after the method has been called the console tells me the right height - 0 or 100 - but the view still remains unchanged.

Comment: After some random tests, I realised that the `-viewWillLayoutSubviews:` method is called after the `setFrame:` method is called. Now I understand where the problem comes from, but as far as I remember, I never had that before. Is this normal? Is there a way to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem in your case is the fact that in `-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews` method you set, lets say the default frame of your view, if you try to change the frame in other methods after the setFrame is called on your view, the `-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews` will also be called and the frame of the view will be the default one. Try to remove the setFrame from your `-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 1):

Is your view controller set up in storyboards, and are you using Autolayout (which is on by default?) If so, setFrame won't work and you need to edit constraints after creating outlets to them from the storyboard.

Alternatively, you can turn off Autolayout in your storyboard, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201586/nsinvalidunarchiveoperationexception-could-not-instantiate-class-named-nslayout).

Comment: Hello, I am not using storyboard.

Comment: Is Autolayout on by default even if I don't use storyboards?

Comment: Storyboards or xibs, from ios6 onwards. If you're not using it, my answer is useless.

Comment: Man, yuo Rule! The views superview in .xib had the "Autoresize subviews" flag on ^_^