# iOS application crashes on launch

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, jailbreak

I am currently using Xcode 4.6.3 which is having iOS6.1 installed. I managed to deploy my application to my jailbroken iPhone4 with iOS5.1 installed.

However whenever I try to launch the application in my iphone device, it crashes. I have followed these steps,

1. Change `SDKSettings.plist` to 'NO' on  `CODE_SINGING_REQUIRED` and `ENTITLEMENTS_REQUIRED`
2. Restart Xcode to change the following settings to my project

   - iOS Deployment target to 4.3 so that it supports iOS4.3 and above)
   - Build Settings > Architectures to armv7 since I am using an iPhone4
   - Build Settings > Base SDK Latest iOS(6.1)
   - Build Settings > Build Active Architecture only **Yes**
   - Build Settings > Valid Architectures armv7
   - Code Signing > ALL (Don't Code Sign)
3. Build my Xcode project with iPhone and not simulator
4. Copy the `.app` out
5. `chmod  -R -775` to my application
6. Fake signing using `./ldid -S test.app/test`
7. scp to my iphone ( using usbmuxd to ssh)
8. relaunch SpringBoard (`killall -HUP SpringBoard`)

I was wondering if my current ldid doesn't support fat binaries (armv7s) and hence I tried to get another copy which supports it but its still does not work. I also took out armv7s since I am not using iPhone5 and did not include armv6 since its not supported after Xcode 4.5.

Any help would be appreciated.
This is a test app which I created just to test the deployment. There is only 1 button inside so its very likely that the problem comes from my configuration settings

1 of the crash logs

```
Incident Identifier: 616F0CD6-1246-4D09-B06B-1C6A2094C2FC
CrashReporter Key:   e4e9497cba20b2026a2ea685d2fd24f8bb65286b
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         test2 [199]
Path:            /Applications/test2.app/test2
Identifier:      test2
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-12-04 20:40:45.583 +0800
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x3713d88f 0x34e42259 0x3713d789 0x3713d7ab 0x310f854d 0x310f86bb 0x310f8423 0x31089001 0x30ff73c7 0x30ed4c59 0x30e4ac17 0x30e49461 0x30e3be87 0x30eac7d5 0xba5ad 0x30e49cab 0x30e437dd 0x30e11ac3 0x30e11567 0x30e10f3b 0x3385322b 0x37111523 0x371114c5 0x37110313 0x370934a5 0x3709336d 0x30e4286b 0x30e3fcd5 0xba1d9 0xba128)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x312f432c 0x312e3000 + 70444
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x339f1208 0x339a4000 + 315912
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x339ea298 0x339a4000 + 287384
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x36877f64 0x36871000 + 28516
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x36875346 0x36871000 + 17222
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34e42350 0x34e39000 + 37712
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x368753be 0x36871000 + 17342
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3687544a 0x36871000 + 17482
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3687681e 0x36871000 + 22558
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34e422a2 0x34e39000 + 37538
10  CoreFoundation                  0x37093506 0x37084000 + 62726
11  CoreFoundation                  0x37093366 0x37084000 + 62310
12  UIKit                           0x30e42864 0x30e0e000 + 215140
13  UIKit                           0x30e3fcce 0x30e0e000 + 203982
14  test2                           0x000ba1d2 0xb9000 + 4562
15  test2                           0x000ba120 0xb9000 + 4384

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x312e43a8 0x312e3000 + 5032
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x30269ea4 0x3025d000 + 52900
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x30269bc2 0x3025d000 + 52162

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x312f4cd4 0x312e3000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x339acf36 0x339a4000 + 36662
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x339accc8 0x339a4000 + 36040

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x312e4004 0x312e3000 + 4100
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x312e41fa 0x312e3000 + 4602
2   CoreFoundation                  0x371113ec 0x37084000 + 578540
3   CoreFoundation                  0x37110124 0x37084000 + 573732
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3709349e 0x37084000 + 62622
5   CoreFoundation                  0x37093366 0x37084000 + 62310
6   WebCore                         0x32a3cc9c 0x32993000 + 695452
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x339b272e 0x339a4000 + 59182
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x339b25e8 0x339a4000 + 58856

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x312f4cd4 0x312e3000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x339acf36 0x339a4000 + 36662
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x339accc8 0x339a4000 + 36040

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3ebacd98      r6: 0x00000002      r7: 0x2feb7b78
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x36878a4a     r10: 0x3e294f60     r11: 0x00000003
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2feb7b6c      lr: 0x339f120f      pc: 0x312f432c
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
   0xb9000 -    0xbbfff +test2 armv7  <192ec58535dd3341b6edbb7cd4cad16c> /Applications/test2.app/test2
0x2feb8000 - 0x2fed9fff  dyld armv7  <77eddfd654df393ba9c95ff01715fd08> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30065000 - 0x300b1fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <b8f80d5d594c31d2b5d8fba9fdedb7e1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x3025d000 - 0x30273fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9ecfaef4110a3bf9a92d12f0fe8d1d78> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x30274000 - 0x3028afff  DictionaryServices armv7  <6ed2e967136f37d4a4b9b318d6c43b83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x3029c000 - 0x302a5fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <4a15e845dc6f3a4a980de66c1cc44c42> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x30448000 - 0x30486fff  IOKit armv7  <fcda71d29d6136dfbd84c1725f4998e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x30487000 - 0x3048dfff  MobileIcons armv7  <ed1b46f917903c9b9baaa2be4392dafe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x30501000 - 0x30501fff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <e0a73a57795f3e1698a52ebe6fc07005> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x30524000 - 0x3052afff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <aa2bcba6fc7a36a191958fef2e995475> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x3054f000 - 0x30550fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <6a8f2f33c7543808a0f4599101c3b61a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x30703000 - 0x30707fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <9a17d07b5a3b38cfafdf16f78c99b572> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x30708000 - 0x30748fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <40448706190031f6b0d9636cc11ee81d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x30d2e000 - 0x30d51fff  Bom armv7  <c3435ecd2e5839f89de51edad0e1bb00> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x30d5a000 - 0x30d70fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <258bc92be5823b239b4412dd42cb4807> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x30da5000 - 0x30da6fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <977b0ad6f2f433108b4a0324a57cd2ab> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x30da7000 - 0x30dbdfff  EAP8021X armv7  <952fcfdec0633aff923768fca1a26fcb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x30dc0000 - 0x30dc3fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <e52b77623bd031bc807e77029566c777> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x30ddf000 - 0x30de0fff  CoreSurface armv7  <97f871f09f503c98a6371c2b657430d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x30e0e000 - 0x312b0fff  UIKit armv7  <cd513a2f22f53d698c3e10f6fe48a63e> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x312e3000 - 0x312f9fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <311f379a9fde305d80c1b22b7dd2e52a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x312fa000 - 0x3131efff  PrintKit armv7  <08509c7bc915358b953de6f5cbef5c56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x313a4000 - 0x313dffff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <55941c96cf1f3b048e72a148c4496c16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x31411000 - 0x31469fff  CoreAudio armv7  <be335e8eb6f93594b028a6ddd503a183> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x31486000 - 0x314cffff  AddressBook armv7  <b17a2962e9043e0385c3c2c652155f2b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x314ee000 - 0x314f8fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <40e4045fb79e382b8833707746cf28b1> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x314f9000 - 0x3151efff  OpenCL armv7  <f4b08361179a3f6bb033415b0d7c6251> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x3152a000 - 0x3152bfff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <9aede8d6579d3430ac39ae5f95cce498> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x3152c000 - 0x3159cfff  CoreImage armv7  <86ac6f5a267637b6b7f8a831dfc7c64b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x3159d000 - 0x315e6fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <5b690e5dd5a43a7fb166ade9fe58a7a4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x315e7000 - 0x315ebfff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <42dbc26828e934acabb4f3b0a35d8250> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x316d3000 - 0x316dffff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <bdb2b4d1a78c39c1ba60d791207aed2a> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x316e0000 - 0x3175ffff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <bf01f5ed47b033d8bde30d735ff44416> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3192f000 - 0x31935fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <e1f06241ef0e3f0aae00f15df572077e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x31936000 - 0x31987fff  CoreText armv7  <5bfac4ee88d03d5b87a1f105abb7756c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x31988000 - 0x3198cfff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <3a3a33f3a05538988c6e2bb363dc46a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x319eb000 - 0x319fafff  OpenGLES armv7  <e80acc691001301e96101bb89d940033> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x31a24000 - 0x31a2afff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <9e45ce468a6f31e5b8263f2c224aa800> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x3243f000 - 0x3243ffff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <ebd2dddf55d83cf48a18913968775960> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x327da000 - 0x327dbfff  DataMigration armv7  <d77f0e8f39ee37f5a2ac713a3fd9e693> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x32866000 - 0x32875fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <a2363f8ed49932dba415d2d4cd32fb74> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x32931000 - 0x32968fff  Security armv7  <eea56f71fde83c2981f9281dc7823725> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x3298c000 - 0x3298ffff  CoreTime armv7  <a398de5ba1e43a11b7008e9bb5a7f6fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x32993000 - 0x33152fff  WebCore armv7  <2690c38c9c5f3c09975d619dd1dfbed7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x33155000 - 0x3319ffff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <f1fbb825def23043830a095b953a9c94> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x331a0000 - 0x331b5fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x3326b000 - 0x3328afff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <0c55744b6f7335eebba4ca2c3d10b43c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x3328b000 - 0x3328efff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <b2c05d8601c13be884097192dca4e187> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x3328f000 - 0x33292fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <f5cc4b97ce9432da9426f12621453325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x3359e000 - 0x33676fff  vImage armv7  <caf3648be2933384b6aa1ae7408ab4f0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x3384e000 - 0x33858fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <cb64e146a8ee3fda9e80ffae1ccc9c5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x33860000 - 0x33898fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <9f25f38d1cd13a1daff99cfde8884410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x338f3000 - 0x338fbfff  MobileWiFi armv7  <b76c3e9fb78234c392058250d4620e72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x339a4000 - 0x33a30fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <f859ce1ad1773f0ba98d7c6e135b7697> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x33a3e000 - 0x33a40fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <215d93dbb0f63cbf828f9126eb7b5349> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x33a4b000 - 0x33a57fff  CoreVideo armv7  <364fa32d513f3c11b50970120545f1a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x33abc000 - 0x33abdfff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <9fdc27af7350323bbc7d98e14e027907> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x33ad9000 - 0x33adafff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <402f8956975d3b6fb86ab9b31a43242c> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x33adb000 - 0x33b85fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <bf822cc1a3243ae7b104cf73ca22d352> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x33f49000 - 0x33f4dfff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d6a7436ed8dc33d795c9b42baf864882> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x33f4e000 - 0x33ffbfff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <58d47f064e0232119f4b838ad659f9c1> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x33ffc000 - 0x342bdfff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <0e94e9a7e7a334649afaccae0f1215a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x3430b000 - 0x344c8fff  ImageIO armv7  <02e3578171fa3b6a969b244275fd2bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x34698000 - 0x346b8fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <39348471007e39dab80af68b08390456> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x34827000 - 0x3482bfff  IOSurface armv7  <443ac3aab9283da480dd9dcda3c5c88e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x3483d000 - 0x3483dfff  Accelerate armv7  <55b24cf91a8b3532bde6733c96f14c08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x3483e000 - 0x3484ffff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <ccf25b1e49ce3b2fa58d8c8546755505> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x34870000 - 0x349b9fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <b70646b63f1f3b33896dd8cb91b8dab1> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x34b8e000 - 0x34cd3fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <903545b89a7f311d95100ac7d1d44709> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x34d2b000 - 0x34d2ffff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <998fccc16cf735dbb62324202995e193> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x34da9000 - 0x34df3fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <441b42aca07b3da39feab25f8349918f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x34df4000 - 0x34e38fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <757226927a873d5492be721908077b48> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x34e39000 - 0x34efffff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <90014d1bc583366d85622e43097df416> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x34f09000 - 0x34f3efff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <4464a4e3bb3f32f7abaa35ebf31fda49> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x35034000 - 0x35039fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <52e874396c393ed29099789ce702cfe2> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x353d9000 - 0x354fefff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <2ffc6c87b94434288366bd53765ee267> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x3553b000 - 0x35629fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <2cfefe2ad1d335dd9549562910e7a2e2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x3562d000 - 0x35635fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <0e846afacf823d2b8c029cc3010a8253> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x35636000 - 0x35706fff  WebKit armv7  <3c5dd2ec46fe3e189c25bba78ad88fa1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x35897000 - 0x35910fff  ProofReader armv7  <6db611d8df6530d480f97a40bc519f70> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x35912000 - 0x35918fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9406297de3e43742887890662a87ab53> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x35922000 - 0x35924fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <d4d4aa3090c83e87bcb15ed00b93fd5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x35dab000 - 0x35dc8fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <50863bcbf478323e96a8e5b1a83ea6f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x35ed7000 - 0x35f13fff  AppSupport armv7  <311eac85b2a433a884dacba77217b49e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x35f14000 - 0x36458fff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <f326d88709683520b251dc53cb847c11> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x36459000 - 0x364aafff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <c352af5a742e3c7a8d4d7e5f6f454793> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x364b7000 - 0x364c2fff  AccountSettings armv7  <373e59421d983c93931cfbad87b1ae35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x36588000 - 0x365d0fff  CoreMedia armv7  <e274e1b894753b2eb05cf7b22a36d0c1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x365fc000 - 0x367e0fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <c91e27850452330ea804db6408840fd2> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x367e4000 - 0x367e7fff  NetworkStatistics armv7  <7848d8ebad99367cb4f7f4e3fe88e5d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x367e8000 - 0x36836fff  CoreLocation armv7  <44550ebedf23334d85441d9743b74e03> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x3686b000 - 0x36870fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <27bb5462450732e380f5a2c170546e93> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x36871000 - 0x36878fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <bab4dcbfc5943d3fbb637342d35e8045> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x36bbd000 - 0x36bc7fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <e8248c797b9b363594bb652ddf7ce16d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x36c00000 - 0x36c00fff  vecLib armv7  <a2cfe25e77aa36bfb4a30b2d0d2dd465> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x36c0f000 - 0x36c20fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <e6144ba265da3bb7b9a263aa1a29b054> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x36d6d000 - 0x36db2fff  GeoServices armv7  <a26be2e76e8730ab91a16502aba376be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x36dc6000 - 0x36e9dfff  CFNetwork armv7  <765a472c824830eea91b8f02d12867e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x36ecd000 - 0x36ecdfff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <644ff4bcfbf337b5b5859e3f0fc0a9a8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x36ece000 - 0x36ecefff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <eb82984fa36c329387aa518aa5205f3d> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x37010000 - 0x3701cfff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <36ce86a3dc8c344596c8c325615f374b> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x37084000 - 0x3719bfff  CoreFoundation armv7  <6d450fe923d7387f8b01845e0edd713d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x371ba000 - 0x371c1fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <38132ecfd74b325fb1a4142bab663c19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x3725c000 - 0x3734

    dfff  QuartzCore armv7  <35d64a9da5523ae08c9e41511fd3061b> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
    0x37411000 - 0x3742afff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <1828cddc5dd93c61afbefb59587d7f8a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
    0x37682000 - 0x37696fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <54091a638f8731cd85ccf00fa06972c3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
    0x376b2000 - 0x376b5fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <356cb66612e836968ef24e6e5c3364cc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x376b8000 - 0x376fbfff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <95b49daf4cf038b6bea8010bba3a1e26> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x376fc000 - 0x3770bfff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d84c3fd0e7bd36e78c256f2f4c5a4e91> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
    0x3770d000 - 0x3770dfff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <a80aaa9989483ce3a496a061fd1e9e0a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
    0x37826000 - 0x37833fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <750a0de73a733019a77144b805d4d2f8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
    0x37913000 - 0x37a91fff  Foundation armv7  <c40ddb073142315bb4ebb214343d0b7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
```

Comment: Can you post the crash logs as well?

Comment: @Amar I have edited the crash log in

Comment: did you find anything strange in the crash log?

Comment: No, sorry I cannot make out anything from the crash logs. Try device debugging through Xcode, add exception breakpoint and see if you can catch the issue.

Comment: It looks like error in your application. Problems with signature would give you different error. You should also check the console output when you launch your application.

Comment: i am able to run successfully in the stimulator( since its just a button inside) but not when I try to launch it on my iphone device

Comment: Your app crashed due to an exception. Try to read the console log in Xcode > Window > Organizer > Device > (your iphone4) > Console, you may find the exception message there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after having several comments suggesting to debug in the console, I tried it out and managed to solve the problem. I was having an error of

```
NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException: Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint
```

I was deploying  to an IOS5 device which does not have `Autolayout` feature supported which is further explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201586/nsinvalidunarchiveoperationexception-could-not-instantiate-class-named-nslayout/13201690#13201690). Hope anyone who encountered a similar problem find this useful