# How can I give my App multi language support?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocalizedstring

How can I give my App multi language supportd?

I know it is possible with `NSLocalizedString`, but I don't know how to do it.
iam new to iPhone dev.

Comment: check this http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial

Comment: this questions answer will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312936/how-to-localize-an-ios-storyboard

Comment: Localization is a big topic and the question "how do I do it" is too broad. Is there a specific thing you want to achieve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to localize an iphone app for different languages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118425/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-for-different-languages)

Comment: i already gone through the link..
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial. but i couldn't find a plus button in my localization pane as in the tutorial. iam working with ios4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]One of the simplest tutorial from Ray can help you a lot. U can follow this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial

Its really simple and easy to understand.
Hope this works for you \m/
EDIT: 
you can refer to this screenshot in order to overcome "+" problem which has been changed in latest xcode.

Comment: thanx.. but i already gone through it, some of them not working in my xcode 4.5.

Comment: You can have a look at this question in stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118425/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-for-different-languages , can you elaborate what is not working in your xcode 4.5 ?

Comment: i already gone through the link.. raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial. but i couldn't find a plus button in my localization pane as in the tutorial

Comment: well i was searching here and there, found some usefull articles, hope they help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596386/no-plus-or-minus-button-in-xcode-localization-settings AND http://new2objectivec.blogspot.in/2012/09/localisation-in-xcode-45-drives-me-crazy.html